# Unable to use nipyapi in spite of it being in the pip list (project)

Tags: python, automation, python-3.6, apache-nifi, nipyapi

I am new to Python and Nifi and I have been asked to use nipyapi for automation testing and connect with my nifi dev board.
[image: CMDScreenshot]
As you can see in the above screenshot, when I pip install nipyapi, it says the requirement is already satisfied. But when I try to import it in my Python project, it says 'no module name nipyapi'. I am using Python v3.6.

Comment: Do you have more than 1 python environment installed? Is pip installing to the correct one?

Comment: No Sdairs, I just have one python environment installed, v3.6.8.